# Classifying the Deal Stage for Investor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table from which there is a sequential series of investments followed by the investor that contributed to the investment. There can't be two investors on the same investment #, but only the first deal an investor invests in is "New" with every future deal listed as "Not New".

I have two columns right now - Investment & Investor, and need to figure out the SQL for writing the third column which is ROUND.

The example output is listed below

```
INVESTMENT | INVESTOR |  ROUND  | <-- THIRD COLUMN DOESN"T EXIST CURRENTLY
---------------------------------
|    1     |    A     |  NEW    |
|    2     |    B     |  NEW    |
|    3     |    A     | NOT NEW |
|    4     |    C     |  NEW    |
|    5     |    D     |  NEW    |
|    6     |    B     | NOT NEW |
|    7     |    C     | NOT NEW |
|    8     |    A     | NOT NEW |
|    9     |    E     |  NEW    | 
|   10     |    A     | NOT NEW |
---------------------------------
```

Appreciate any thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by investor order by investment) = 1
             then 'NEW' else 'NOT NEW'
        end) as round
from t;
```